# Can batch or Windows cmd file create or release mutex?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, mutex

Can batch or Windows cmd file create or release mutex, without custom exe?

Similar questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110495/single-instance-batch-file)) tell only to write custom c exe.

**Can I work with mutex from bare batch script, or only with use a some Windows standard utils?**

**UPD**

I do not need the single instance bat, I need to work with mutex to send the message to already exist parent-process with known mutex. Temp file is not an answer.

**UPD 2**

1. Parent program have the mutex (I use the `hMutex:=CreateMutex( nil, TRUE, 'VCSClient2r123r123refqwe' );` in program startups, to prevent the multiple instances of parent program.
2. Parent program run `svn.exe diff "some_modified_file" --diff-cmd "diff.bat" --force`
3. `diff.bat` should send some messages to parent program. Because mutex is already exist and mutex name are fixed, I want to use it to send info from `diff.bat` to parent process.

Comment: You might be able to do it [using PowerShell](http://learn-powershell.net/2014/09/30/using-mutexes-to-write-data-to-the-same-logfile-across-processes-with-powershell/).

Comment: u could definitely do it in PS, but in essence you'd be building a program (as a dynamic DLL) to do so. Which in some respects is same as developing a custom C program. Suggest downloading Winobj and see if the mutex shows up in the \GLOBAL?? namespace. (Some items in the \GLOBAL?? name space are accessible by Win32 command line programs - if they're written to allow it.) If it does appear u might be able to find a command to determine if the mutex exists or not. But u wouldn't know if it's set/reset. On my system named mutexes are in \BaseNamedObjects, but there are no aliases in \GLOBAL??